kdb+/q How to perform a string search replace when dealing with mixed lists
I want to perform a string search replace on a list but the list has items of different sizes so it is more complex
q)d1
"['null', 'work']"
"['verse']"
"['hi', 'fire']"
"['null']"
"['null', 'echo']"
"['pause']"
"['null', 'hi']"
"['null', 'cheek']"
"['lamb', 'null']"


q)fargs
"w"
"h"
"f"
"s"
"a"

q)sargs
"help"
"yes"
"no"
"why"
"when"

Current attempt
{{ssr[x;y;z]}[x;;]'[fargs;sargs]}each d1

I'm expecting to have d1 returned exactly how it looks with any words in sargs replacing any letters in fargs.
What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Can you pass the data in a different format (i.e. JSON) which would allow you to iterate over the entries more efficiently?

It's not exactly clear what your desired result is, but this is an implementation that replaces each occurrence of fargs with the corresponding value in sargs.
q)ssr/[;fargs;sargs]each d1
"['null', 'yewhyelpork']"
"['verwhye']"
"['yewhyi', 'noire']"
"['null']"
"['null', 'ecyewhyo']"
"['pwhenuwhye']"
"['null', 'yewhyi']"
"['null', 'cyewhyeek']"
"['lwhenmb', 'null']"

Note that this is done sequentially i.e. after one replacement if any letters from fargs are introduced they may be replaced later. We can see this using scan (\) instead of over (/):
q)ssr\[;fargs;sargs]first d1
"['null', 'helpork']"
"['null', 'yeselpork']"
"['null', 'yeselpork']"
"['null', 'yewhyelpork']"
"['null', 'yewhyelpork']"


It turns out this simple-sounding task is much more complex if you dont want the recursive/sequential replacements as per Cillians answer. If you only want replacements at the initial top level then something like this could work (there could also be a simpler way that I'm overlooking):
q)d1:("['null', 'work']";"['verse']";"['hi', 'fire']";"['null']";"['null', 'echo']";"['pause']";"['null', 'hi']";"['null', 'cheek']";"['lamb', 'null']");
q)fargs:"whfsa"
q)sargs:("help";"yes";"no";"why";"when")

q)toplevelSSR:{$[null 1+m:min raze i:ss[x]each y;x;raze@[;1;.z.s[;y;z]]@[;0;'[raze;ssr[;y s;z s]]]cut[0,m+count y s:first where m in/:i;x]]};
q)toplevelSSR[;fargs;sargs]each d1
"['null', 'helpork']"
"['verwhye']"
"['yesi', 'noire']"
"['null']"
"['null', 'ecyeso']"
"['pwhenuwhye']"
"['null', 'yesi']"
"['null', 'cyeseek']"
"['lwhenmb', 'null']"


To follow on from Terry's answer, this is a simpler top-level only replacement:
q){raze@[s;i;:;x i:where""~/:s:z y?x]}[;fargs;sargs]each d1
"['null', 'helpork']"
"['verwhye']"
"['yesi', 'noire']"
"['null']"
"['null', 'ecyeso']"
"['pwhenuwhye']"
"['null', 'yesi']"
"['null', 'cyeseek']"
"['lwhenmb', 'null']"


Nice. Note that this will only work (currently) for single character fargs like in this example. It would not work for say fargs:("wo";"h";"f";"s";"a")
